# Moving code from codeplex to google code - keeping history

Tags: svn

I am currently in the process of moving my code hosting from codeplex to google code for various reasons.

I have my code in subversion, is there anyway that I can move the code from one site to the other and keep the commit history on the files or would it be best to do a fresh import?

Answer (score 1):

[How do I import an existing Subversion repository?](http://code.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=56673&topic=10386) or a more complete tutorial

[Importing Subversion Repositories to Google Code](http://therightstuff.de/CommentView,guid,b984a8e7-e94d-4eed-a705-5dc479f959e8.aspx)

Comment: I have read those but they only deal with local repositories or ones that you have access to, and in codeplexes case I don't have access.

Comment: Well I suggest you setup a local svn server and first create a local svn repository by using svnsync to "copy" the repository from codeplex to your localsystem. That should work

Comment: @jitter, you can also svnsync directly to the remote repository at google code

Comment: I'm not sure if codeplex supports being the source (or destination for that matter) for svnsync

Comment: I tried to use svnsync against codeplex but it gave me this error:
svnsync: Repository has not been enabled to accept revision propchanges;
ask the administrator to create a pre-revprop-change hook

Looks like I'll just have to put up with having no history, project is still young so it's no big deal

Comment: if you're moving *from* codeplex, the codeplex repository doesn't need a pre-revprop-change hook. The google repository does (and it has one). Maybe you mixed the source and destination? You should clear the repository at google code, because it has to start at revision 0 (default is at revision 1)